# datetime comparision in javascript is not working

Tags: javascript, validation, datetime

I want to validate dateTime input fields in form and it need to give alert message if not entered and if "FromDate"(ex:17-12-2013 19:14:58) > than the "CurrentDate" it need to give alert message in the same way "ToDate" > than the "CurrentDate" it need to give mes and if "FromDate">"ToDate" in that cse also it need to give some alert message i written code for it but it is not working can any one help me?
Code wiill be like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>     
<%@ taglib uri="http://displaytag.sf.net" prefix="display" %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
 <title>Preva Tracking Systems</title>
<link rel="icon" href="pictures/preva_logo.png" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/screen.css" type="text/css">  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/site.css" type="text/css">  
<link href="css/sty.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/datetimepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/overspeedvalidate.js" >
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form  name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="ReportGenerator?action=OverspeedEventDBReport" method="post">
<table width=100% border="1">
            <tr bgcolor=#075A99 >
            <td width=100% align=left><b><font color=white>OverSpeed Event Report</font></b></td>

            </tr>
            </table>



               <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="reportSearchBorder">
                  <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
                   <tr>
                       <td width="100%">
                                    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border=0>           
                                      <tr>
                                          <td  align="left" id="VehicleIdDescDiv" valign="middle">Vehicle Number</td>
                                             <td >
                                                    <table align=left border=0>
                                                       <tr>
                                                        <td  align=left>
                                                            <select name="vehicleId"  class="txtbig" ><option value="">Select vehicle number</option>
                                                              <c:forEach var="vehiclelist" items="${devicelists}">
                                                                <option value="${vehiclelist.deviceID}">${vehiclelist.description}</option>
                                                                </c:forEach></select>

                                                     </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr><td align="center"></td></tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                         <td valign="middle"></td>

                                                     </tr>

                                                  </table>
                                               </td><td  id="VehicleIdDescDiv" valign="middle">Show overspeed instances more than</td>
                                               <td >
                                                              <select name="speed"   class="txtbig" >
                                                                <option value="">Select</option>
                                                                <option value="&gt;100km">&gt;100km</option>
                                                                <option value="&gt;90km">&gt;90km</option>
                                                                <option value="&gt;80km">&gt;80km</option>
                                                                <option value="&gt;70km">&gt;70km</option>
                                                                <option value="&gt;60km">&gt;60km</option>
                                                                <option value="&gt;50km">&gt;50km</option>
                                                                <option value="&gt;40km">&gt;40km</option>
                                                                <option value="&gt;30km">&gt;30km</option>
                                                                <option value="&gt;20km">&gt;20km</option>
                                                                <option value="&gt;10km">&gt;10km</option>
                               </select>  </td>
                                  </tr></table>

                <table>

                             <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
                      <tr>
                           <td width="60%">

<table>


<tr><td>From Date</td>
    <td>
            <input type="Text" name="AnotherDate" id="demo1" maxlength="25" size="25"><a href="javascript:NewCal('demo1','ddMMyyyy',true,24)"><img src="pictures/cal.gif" width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="select"></a>
            <br>(eg:- 17-12-2013 19:14:58)
    </td>
        <td>To Date</td>
    <td>
            <input type="Text" id="demo2" name="ADate" maxlength="25" size="25"><a href="javascript:NewCal('demo2','ddMMyyyy',true,24)"><img src="pictures/cal.gif" width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="select"></a>
            <br>(eg:- 17-12-2013 19:14:58)
    </td> 

 </tr>
</table>




</td>
        </tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="60%"><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>

                <td align="right"><input type="submit" value="Show Report" class="button1"></td>

            </tr>
        </table></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
</table>

            </td>   
            </tr>
        </table>                
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

overspeedvalidate.js Code wiil be like this:

```
function validateForm() {

    var todayDate = new Date();
    var fromDate=document.myForm.AnotherDate.value;
    var toDate=document.myForm.ADate.value;
    var fromparts = fromDate.split(" ");
    var fromdate= fromparts[0];
    var fromtime=fromparts[1];
    var fromdayfield = fromdate.split("-")[0];
    var frommonthfield = fromdate.split("-")[1];
    var fromyearfield = fromdate.split("-")[2];
    var fromhourfield = fromtime.split(":")[0];
    var fromminfield = fromtime.split(":")[1];
    var fromsecfield = fromtime.split(":")[2];


  var toparts = toDate.split(" ");
  var todate= toparts[0];
  var totime=toparts[1];
  var todayfield = todate.split("-")[0];
  var tomonthfield = todate.split("-")[1];
  var toyearfield = todate.split("-")[2];
  var tohourfield = totime.split(":")[0];
  var tominfield = totime.split(":")[1];
  var tosecfield = totime.split(":")[2];

  var fromDate = new Date(fromyearfield, frommonthfield-1, fromdayfield,fromhourfield,fromminfield,fromsecfield);
  var toDate = new Date(toyearfield, tomonthfield-1, todayfield,tohourfield,tominfield,tosecfield);

    if(document.myForm.vehicleId.selectedIndex ==0 ){
        alert("Please select vehicle number");
        document.myForm.vehicleId.focus();
        return false;
    }else if (document.myForm.speed.selectedIndex == 0){
        alert("Please select Speed");
        return false;
    }else if (document.myForm.AnotherDate.value == null || document.myForm.AnotherDate.value == ""){
        alert("Please select FromDate");
        document.myForm.AnotherDate.focus();
        return false;
    }else if (fromDate.getTime()>todayDate.getTime()){
        alert("Please select FromDate lessthan CurrentDate");
        document.myForm.AnotherDate.focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if (document.myForm.ADate.value == null || document.myForm.ADate.value == ""){
        alert("Please select ToDate");
        document.myForm.ADate.focus();
        return false;
    }else if(toDate.getTime()>todayDate.getTime()){
        alert("Please select ToDate lessthan CurrentDate");
        document.myForm.ADate.focus();
        return false;
    }else if (fromDate.getTime()>toDate.getTime()){
        alert("Please select FromDate lessthan ToDate");
        document.myForm.AnotherDate.focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

when i consider only upto date it is working fine but when i consider both date and time it is not working can any solve my problem

Comment: check your console log. your code have some errors. you declaring fromDate and toDate two times

Comment: I think it not a problem since for the same var i am creating date objects.I tried with different names also

Comment: what you exactly want?

Comment: i need validation for input dateTime coming like "22-1-2014 13:14:15"

Comment: did you need to check the from date is lesser than current date or not right?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried a javascript function as in the following fiddle it works for me.
Just comapare two date variables with date-time format it will works

http://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/1307/

function change(){

```
   //            new Date(Year, Month, Date, Hr, Min, Sec);
   var dateOne = new Date(2012, 04, 20, 14, 55, 59);
   var dateTwo = new Date(2012, 04, 20, 12, 10, 20);
    //Note: 04 is month i.e. May
   if (dateOne > dateTwo) {
        alert("Date One is greather then Date Two.");
    }else {
        alert("Date Two is greather then Date One.");
    }
```

}

Comment: when i am doing seperatly by hardcoding data mycode also working fine but when it is comes for dynamically data it is giving problem

Comment: then log the fromDate and toDate in console whether it is correct or not. You may get the solution